# Changing the color of a div - HTML

Tags: html, css, colors

I have a dropdown menu with a sub-menu, made up of lists:

```
<ul>
   <li class="list_item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="list_item">Item 2</li>
      <ul>
         <li class="sub_list_item">Sub Item 1</li>
         <li class="sub_list_item">Sub Item 2</li>
      </ul>
   <li class="list_item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS changes the `background-color` of these items when hovered on.
What I want to do is keep `Item 2`'s background color changed whilst hovering over any give `Sub Item`

Any simple way to do this?

CSS:

```
.list_item:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
.sub_list_item:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Please show your CSS.

Comment: Your CSS does not match your HTML - there is no `a` tag in your HTML.

Comment: There is and I apologize, I was just being lazy

Comment: your submenu isn't a child of the one of the main menu's items.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap item 2 around its `<ul>` tag

```
<ul>
   <li class="list_item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="list_item">Item 2
      <ul>
         <li class="sub_list_item">Sub Item 1</li>
         <li class="sub_list_item">Sub Item 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="list_item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the direct child selector `>` to target a specific `li` as opposed any given `li` or `ul`.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKaEZ/) - menu I made a few weeks ago

Usage example:

```
#menu > ul > li:hover {
    background: #2580a2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the code and css**

```
<ul class="item">
    <li class="list_item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">Item 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="sub_list_item">Sub Item 1</li>
        <li class="sub_list_item">Sub Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="list_item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS is**

```
.item
{
    color: #000000;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

.item li:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #336600;
}

.item ul li:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

**Enjoy ... and choose your color whatever you like**

for more detail visit ..
http://www.mr-sudhir.com/blog/what-is-css.aspx